# Приоритет на выборку в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как сделать приоритет на группировку или же на выборку данных ?

```
 WHERE content_product_id = "143634"
           AND (content_order_number = "1" OR
                (zone_type_id = 10 AND content_order_number = "special"))
           AND zt.zone_type_id IN (10,12,1)
           AND cell_block = 0
           AND content_product_defect_id = 1
```

Как сделать что бы приоритет был сначала на  `AND (content_order_number = "1"`, а потом уже `zone_type_id = 10 AND content_order_number = "special")`
если не чего не нашло в бд content_order_number = "1" то смотрела уже на content_order_number = "special"
И что бы всегда вверху была запись с content_order_number  = 1 если нашлась такая.

Comment: Такого "приоритета" не бывает. Можно получить всё, соответствующее хотя бы одному из условий (при этом AND заменятся на OR), а потом приоритезировать сортировку результата - например, соответствующим CASE WHEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE content_product_id = "143634"
  AND (content_order_number = "1" OR
      (zone_type_id = 10 AND content_order_number = "special"))
  ...
ORDER BY content_order_number = "1" desc
```

В сортировке доступны любые выражения, а выражения с оператором `=` в MySQL возвращают 0 если условие не сработало и 1 если сработало. Сортируем в обратном порядке, что бы 1 были первыми.

Comment: Вы неправильно поняли суть задачи. Человеку надо не сортировать по этому условию, а выбрать записи, которые подходят под одно условие И ЕСЛИ таких записей нет, то выбрать записи, которые подойдут под другое условие. Ваше решение выберет и записи, которые подойдут под первое условие, и записи, которые подойдут под второе условие.

Comment: Я сейчас перечитал вопрос, и как-то непонятно чего хотел автор. В любом случае либо моё, либо Ваше решение ему подойдет :)

Comment: @HTMLProgrammer С вашим будут сложности, особенно когда оно выполнено в виде хранимой процедуры. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что вот те остальные параметры, особенно `zone_type_id IN (10,12,1)` постоянны. Наверняка надо будет их менять из скрипта, а вот передать их в хранимую процедуру, особенно список как параметры проблематично.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так можно решить

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test//

CREATE PROCEDURE test() BEGIN
    SET @count = 0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @count FROM `users` WHERE `content_order_number` = 1;
    
    IF @count > 0 THEN
        SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `content_order_number` = 1;
     ELSE
        SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `zone_type_id` = 10 AND `content_order_number`="special";
     END IF;
END//

call test()//
```